# Windows service won't start when using other credentials from active directory

Tags: windows, service, timeout

I have created a windows service. The OnStart method only exists of a Timer setup:

```
Timer startupTimer = new Timer();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  startupTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(startupTimer_Elapsed);
  startupTimer.Interval = 60000;
  startupTimer.Enabled = true;
  startupTimer.AutoReset = false;
}
```

When I install the service, and run it directly (log on as: 'Local System Account') it works perfectly, it starts within 2 seconds. But, the service needs to acces a network share with special permissions. Therefore I setup 'Log on as: [domain\user-account]'. When I then start the service, it takes more than 30 seconds and I receive the following error message: **The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fasion.**

Searching for this error gives a lot of solutions, but (as far as I googled) never related to different credentials. I doubt that setting the time-out value from 30 seconds to 60 seconds will help, because the OnStart code is very small. Also, it's a production server which I can't reboot just to try another TimeOut setting in the registry.

Does someone has any ideas/suggestions for me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do u have any code in service class constructor or static/type constructors? That can be one reason. To debug the issue, you may run your service executable under the specific user and attach debugger to it - of course, you have to modify your main entry point to run the similar start-up code in the service class instead of calling `ServiceBase.Run`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to keep the windows service to run as 'Local System Account' and use impersonation to access the network share?

Comment: @VinayC: Thanks for your feedback. De Windows Service runs on a Machine on the customers location. I upload the installer via FTP. At that location, I don't have any dev-tools available.

Comment: @CodeCanvas: It took about 1 hour, but I seemed to get it working - impersonation. Now I must wait for the timers to elapse before I can tell the complete service works ;)

Comment: generally when I create my windows services, in my main entry-point, I put a code that would sniff command line parameters such as "/test" and if found then run it as normal exe (instead of windows service). You should try that - very helpful in finding environment related issues.

Comment: I can repeat this issue, when using 2 different domain credentials. With one credential the service starts immediately, and with the other, the Service Constructor / OnStart wasn't even called within 30 seconds. Eventually after many attempts to start, the service eventually started with both sets of credentials. No idea - some group policy check possibly?